# How to create an Android applicatin module

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

im using android studio to build flutter apps, and for those apps i like to connect to firebase.

now, android studio has this feature where you can very easily connect your flutter app with firebase using the firebase assistant, but every time i try this, it will say

```
Firebase: Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online projects. Create a new Android Application Module or create/import a different Android Studio project.
```

if already deleted and reinstalled android studio, but this does not solve this...

does anyone know how to fix this? this also occurs on newly created projects.

Comment: The Firebase assistant is for Android native applications (and is also mostly broken).  Flutter has its own Firebase integration path.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup